# SQL - Group by Week Ending

Tags: sql

Can someone help me re-write this code to sum the calls by weekending Saturdays?

column headers should be as follows:  Week-Ending, Agent ID, Total Calls

```
SELECT distinct 
cName as "Agent ID"
,CAST(dIntervalStart AS DATE) as "Date"
,SUM(nInternToExternCalls) as "Calls" 

FROM QueueStats

WHERE  
cast(dIntervalStart as date) >= '2019-12-29' and cast(dIntervalStart as date) <= '2020-12-26'

GROUP BY
AQ.cName 
,CAST(dIntervalStart AS DATE)
order by cName
```

Comment: _group by weekending and Sum Count on Saturdays_?

Comment: Make it easy to assist you - show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (no images.) [mcve]

Comment: Week Ending     Agent ID    Total Calls

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

SELECT distinct
cName as "Agent ID"
,DATEADD(DAY, -DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, [dIntervalStart]) % 7, [dIntervalStart]) as "Week-Ending"
,SUM(nInternToExternCalls) as "Calls"

FROM QueueStats

WHERE
cast(dIntervalStart as date) >= '2019-12-29' and cast(dIntervalStart as date) <= '2020-12-26'

GROUP BY
AQ.cName
,DATEADD(DAY, -DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, [dIntervalStart]) % 7, [dIntervalStart])
order by cName